# Two rebus puzzles, each with a sun

Tags: visual, rebus

These two rebus puzzles both have a sun in it.

Puzzle 1:
[image: REBUS_SUN1]

Puzzle 2:
[image: REBUS_SUN2]

What do they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puzzle 1

> The word sun is written with letters increasing in size so it is **Sunrise** also the size increase is in the right direction or east, so it can be **Sunrise in the east**.

Puzzle 2

> The word Sun and down arrow is written in a vest, vest sounds similar to west, so the answer is **Sundown in the west** or **Sunset in the west**.

Comment: You solved the first puzzle, but the second one isn't what I have in mind. Good try though!

Answer (score 4):

The answer should be:

> **Sunrise & Sundown**
>
>  "SUN spelled in RISing letter size" = **"Sunrise"**
>  "SUN with DOWN arrow" = **"Sundown"**

Comment: with respect, what is "sundown"? I have heard "sunset".

Comment: You solve the first puzzle completely and the second puzzle partially. There is something missing in the answer to the second puzzle...

Comment: @Vikram Sundown = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundown